# Collision of ball and object hides

Tags: python, collision-detection, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a block breaker-game and do not know how to properly make a collision detection of a ball and a box that is set-up above it. What it should do it basically when the ball hits this single box, the box has to hide and the ball has to bounce back.

```
from time import sleep
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, Shape

BALL_RADIUS = 5
FONT = ("Arial", 24, "normal")
ball_move_horizontal = 1 
ball_move_vertical = 1 

def draw_ball():
    # BALL
    ball = Turtle()
    ball.penup()
    ball.shape("circle") 
    ball.shapesize(BALL_RADIUS / 10, BALL_RADIUS / 10)  
    ball.sety(BORDER_BOTTOM + 32)
    return ball

def draw_boxes(rows, cols, x, y, w, h):
    color_list = ["cyan", "pink"]
    boxes_list = []
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            box = Turtle("square")
            box.penup()
            box.shapesize(w, h, 3) 
            box.color("white", color_list[(j + i) % 2]) 
            box.goto(x + h * 20 * j, y + w * 20 * i)
            boxes_list.append(box)
    return boxes_list
    boxes_list = draw_boxes(3, 9, -245, 230, 1, 3)
    pass
```

I would love some help in this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you should be able to do this with the `turtle.distance` function. So you can do this:

```py
if ball.distance(box) < 50:
# ball bounces and rectangle hides code
```